# Check if string contains only positive numbers in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I am really new to [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) and want know if it's possible to check if a string contains only positive numbers using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) or some other function?

```
str = "123abcd"  #return false because it contains alphabets
str = "153"      #return true because of all numbers
```

Comment: By "positive digits", I presume you mean 1-9.  Is that correct, or do you mean '0-9' (in which case you should strike "positive")?

Comment: There is no such thing as "positive digits". One or more digits express(es) a number. A number can be positive or not. `0` by itself expresses a non-positive number. The `0` in `10` is part of a positive number. You cannot say whether `0` as a digit is positive or not. Similarly, `1` alone is a positive number. `1` in `-1` is part of a negative number.

Comment: I realized that the original question said "positive numbers" and Wayne edited to "positive digits". The original one was better.

Comment: Interesting. If that's the case, then all the solutions are wrong because of strings like "+15" or "2.0e+40"

Comment: @MarkThomas You are right. The question is actually a difficult one if that is what was intended. The question is not clear for sure.

Comment: Sloppily-worded questions like this one are time-wasting and annoying, doubly-so when the asker takes no action rectify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course `Regexp` is good for this:

```
string = "123abcd"
/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ string
num # => nil

string = "123"
/^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ string
num # => '123' # String
```

So if you need to check the condition:

```
if /^(?<num>\d+)$/ =~ string
   num.to_i # => 123
   # do something...
end
```

`#to_i` method of `String` isn't valid for your case because it will return a number, if string is even with letters:

```
string = "123abcd"
string.to_i # 123
```

Comment: It works, but is inefficient.

Comment: 2nd downvoter are you weak to explain that?

Comment: Wouldn't `/[-+]*\d/` also work? It's a lot simpler

Comment: @Zac the askwer requires to match only positive letter, but your solution will match negative ones, also with an only a first digit, and many +- signs, what is it?

Comment: Oh yeah - I didn't realise it was only positive

Answer (score 20):

All other answers so far using regex are inefficient.

```
"123abcd" !~ /\D/ # => false
"153" !~ /\D/     # => true
```

Comment: So you consider all non-negated regex matches inefficient? I think the difference would be insignificant for most real-world cases.

Comment: In addition to efficiency, those regexes are more complicated. There is no reason to use them.

Comment: I agree, and I voted up your answer because of its simplicity. However, I don't think I'd flag anyone in a code review for using `=~` over `!~`. Regular expressions are still fairly efficient. "Less efficient" != "inefficient".

Comment: It gives wrong value if the string is empty `'' !~ /\D/`

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah No, it doesn't. It correctly returns `true`.

Comment: @sawa, for empty string it should return `false` right?

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah Of course not.

Answer (score 4):

```
if '123'.match(/^\d+$/)
  # code
end
```

Comment: It works, but is inefficient.

Comment: @sawa Can you explain why this is less efficient than your negated answer?

Comment: @MarkThomas When the string contains a non-digit, my regex does not need to carry the information of a matching candidate because (mis-)match is decided by looking at a single character. It just needs to increment the start position to apply the pattern. The regex in this answer has to keep track of the matching candidate information (sequence of digits) up to the point it fails.

Comment: @sawa I don't see how this needs to track anything, as there are no capture groups. As soon as you see a non-digit, this can fail.

Comment: @MarkThomas Having no capture group only means that it does not need to keep track of any substring of the match. But it needs to keep the entire match during the matching process in case it succeeds, even if it eventually turns out to fail. A matchdata object has the information of the entire matched string.

Comment: @sawa Ah, so you not are referring to the regex but the fact that the `match` method returns a MatchData object. Would `"123" =~ /^\d+$/` be better?

Comment: @MarkThomas Still in that case, the matchdata is kept in `$~`.

Answer (score 2):

I' do using [`Regexp#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) as below :

```
str = "123abcd"
/^\d+$/ === str  # => false # because string not only contains digits
str = "153" 
/^\d+$/ === str  # => true  # because string only contains digits
```

**update (considering @sawa's [comment1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814355/check-if-string-contains-only-positive-digits/21814546?noredirect=1#comment33014271_21814546) and [comment2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814355/check-if-string-contains-only-positive-digits/21814546?noredirect=1#comment33014421_21814546)**)

```
str = "123abcd"
/\D/ === str  # => true  # because string contains non-digit
str = "153" 
/\D/ === str  # => false # because string doesn't contain any non-digit
```

Comment: It works, but is inefficient.

Comment: @sawa Thanks for your review. Could you tell me why is it efficient? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: If a string includes a non-digit character, it becomes clear at that point that it should return false, and there is no need to look further into the string. But your regex scans the entire string.

Comment: Actually, the condition is more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: @sawa I joined SO to learn, so tried to improve it. Please review it.

Comment: Good food for thought.

Comment: Using `Regexp#===` in this way is not very idiomatic.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think I am explaining it better in comments to Speransky Danil's answer. Please read there if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

I originally answered this when "only positive digits" was a requirement, but I see that has been changed to "only positive numbers" (the original wording), which, in part because of the example given (which rules out the interpretation `"12abc34" => true`, `"12abc-34" => false` and does not suggest the interpretation `"1.5abc" => true`), I take to mean "one positive integer".  My assumption is stated more precisely by my answer:

```
str =~ /^0*[1-9]\d*$/
```

This question raises another: "How many Rubiests can dance on the head of a pin?".  Maybe it's just a slow-news day.  Thanks to @sawa and @Mark for their comments.

Comment: Logic error: returns `true` for an empty string. You want `+`.

Comment: @Mark, I mulled that, but decided to go with `*`, as I figured the asker did not mean "only positive digits" literally, for if/she did, one could argue that false should be returned for strings of length one, which I don't think was intended.  Was the downvote yours?

Comment: Yes, but I will remove it if you put your (completely valid) interpretation of the unstated requirements in the answer.

Comment: Even more fatal is the fact the no zero is allowed. It excludes numbers like `10`. The question originally said "positive numbers", and was edited by Wayne to "positive digits", which does not have clear meaning.

Comment: @sawa, I wasn't aware of the edit you mentioned, but will fix.  Mark, thanks for the suggestion.  Will do.